# python for absolute beginners chapter 5 challenge #1

Tags: python

I have spent a lot of time to make this work but I can't find a problem with the code.  The program hasto show words in a list with random order.  Please help!

```
novi=[]
while lista==True:
    polozaj=random.randrange(len(lista))
    nov=lista[polozaj]
    no=nov[:]
    novi.append(no) 
    lista.remove(nov)
print(novi)
input("Pritisni enter da izadjes")
```

Comment: You seem to have gotten a good answer to this question, which is great. For future questions on SO though, please also share *why* your existing code isn't working for you. Your question should include detailed descriptions of error messages or the undesired behavior you want to change. This question was looking for a pretty simple outcome, so you got a good answer without a good description of your issue, but when you improve your skills and need help with more difficult issues, you will need to include a description of what *is* happening, instead of just what you want to happen.

Comment: Ok.This is a really small program so I did not write detailed description.

Comment: I understand. Simple problems have simple questions, but asking complete questions is a good habit to get into while you're starting. When you have tougher questions later on, if you post them without descriptions of the observed behavior, you may get a couple of comments asking for clarification, or you may get downvoted into oblivion. Asking good questions is an art, so start practicing it while your questions are (relatively) simple. Good luck learning Python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to destroy the list!

To preserve `lista`:

```
# Python 2.7
to_shuffle = lista[:]
random.shuffle(to_shuffle )
print to_shuffle
```

or, as Jon points out,

```
print random.sample(lista, len(lista))
```

---

If you don't care about it:

```
# Python 2.7
random.shuffle(lista)
print lista
```

[Here is the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: Why not just `random.shuffle(lista)`?

Comment: @FinlayL Well, that `random.shuffle` modifies the list in place, so in case OP would like to preserve the order of `lista`. I've edited to reflect the difference.

Comment: You can also use `sample` and give it the length of the entire list, instead of copying, then shuffling. eg: `random.sample(lista, len(lista))` and that'll return a new list that's basically shuffled.

Comment: But I didn`t read anything about method .shuffle and .sample in this book.So can it be done by adding and removing elements of the list?

Answer (score 2):

Here's **code**:

```
import random
WORDS = ["OVERUSED", "CLAM", "GUAM", "TAFFETA", "PYTHON"]
x = len(WORDS)
count = 0
if count == x:
    exit(0)
while count < (x):

    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    WORDS.remove(word)  
    print(word)
    count += 1
```

**output**:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Projects# python3 randomWords.py
CLAM
PYTHON
TAFFETA
OVERUSED
GUAM
```